# jQuery Relational Web

Tags: flash, jquery-plugins

If you look at the image http://www.pitchinteractive.com/img/mozart_1.jpg, does anyone know of a jQuery plugin that will give a similar sort of diagram and auto-organise?

**edit**

Or perhaps even a flash plugin that I can insert on the page.

Comment: did anyone ever answer this? was there an answer? interested in the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I searched a bit, I think the closest you could find is [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/demos/)
Take a look the demo here: http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html

Might be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: +1, No I never found a solution but the one you found looks awesome.

Comment: good stuff ;)  Coincidentally its the same one I'm looking for per request from a client.